# Safe code in javascript How it handles the global execution context

Tags: javascript, web

This might be a silly question but most of the frameworks start with

```
(function(){
//all data
})()
```

Immediately invoked expression
So that There will be no collision with other js files right,so basically this is a function execution context that gets popped of the stack after execution,
but how come it still could handle asynchronous requests like a click after page has been loaded

For example:

```
(function(){
//all data  
var a=true; 
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
alert(a);
});
})() ;
```

The whole code runs first and an event Listener is given to a button but after,that execution context is popped off the stack so how come my button can still contact and get data from the "finished safecode function"?

Is this an implementation of closures where execution stack gets popped off but still the variables needed for dependant nested functions getting hung up?

Comment: yeah arrow functions Lol was typing faster didnt notice It was a mock example i prepared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's just the behavior of closures: a function always has access to everything declared in its outer blocks (lexical scope), even if the outer blocks have already finished execution. Until those functions don't exist anymore, the variables will continue to exist.

Comment: And the fact, that variable continues to exists, can lead to memory leaks. ;)

Comment: Oh only the inner functions  can access the left off variables,other than that none of the other functions or global context can access it data cant be simply leaked unless the function executing was actually an inner function that was built of from the popped out function context

Answer (score 0):

Inner functions keep a reference of their parents execution context